# Scene with multiple objects - Is it possible to export everything as a single object, but maintain multiple objects in the outliner?

Tags: export, .fbx

Ok, yeah, that might have been a bit confusing as a title...let's see if I can clear it up!

I'm working in Unity and building the geometry for scenes in Blender. This can involve quite a few objects.

[image]
Ideally, I want to join everything up to export it as a single FBX. I could do this by joining.

However, I also want to preserve in Blender everything as a seperate object which allows easier editing.

Does that make sense?

Are there any ways to temporarily join everything up just for export?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out the exporter I'm using 'FBX Bundle' has a setting which solves this very problem:

[image]

This way I can keep my actual Blender scene of multiple objects unjoined, but just export one FBX in Unity :)

Answer (score 1):

Historically, I like to make two files. A working file for editing and a flattened or joined file, saving over or making a new copy of the joined file each time I edit the working file. It stays quite organized with proper naming conventions. I am not aware of another way to accomplish what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this is join and export as you usually do. Later, press Ctrl + Alt + Z. This opens up all the undo steps (going back a few steps).Press the step just before the 'join' command and you are back to your original with multiple objects in outliner.

[image]